# popup dropdown item selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my dropdown menu. code seems ok, no error but it does not alert selected item from menu.

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/DmFXZ/219/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
    $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
        //console.log('found change');
        alert($(this).val());

});
}
```

html:

```
<div id='selectPopup'>
    <form name='test'>
        <select id='inptPAN' name='inptPAN'>
            <option value='1'>item 1</option>
            <option value='2'>item 2</option>
            <option value='3'>item 3</option>
            <option value='4'>item 4</option>
            <option value='5'>item 5</option>
            <option value='6'>item 6</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **no error but it does not alert selected item from menu.**

No the fiddle contains the error, you can see the error in console.

Error is : you are missing end of `$(document).ready`.

Syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
});
```

Try this :

```
 $(document).ready(function () {    
     $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());        
     });
 });
```

[Working Code](http://jsfiddle.net/DmFXZ/220/)

Answer (score 3):

You are not rightly finished the function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
    $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
        //console.log('found change');
        alert($(this).val());

});
});//you missed it
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax of document.ready is the problem here..

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
});
```

You must close the document.ready function with `});` instead of `}`

Your code should look like this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
     $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
            alert($(this).val());        
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete. Put `);` at the end. like the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
    $("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
        //console.log('found change');
        alert($(this).val());

});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// this function is triggered as soon as something changes in the form
$("select[name='inptPAN']").change(function () {
    //console.log('found change');
    alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: Please avoid adding code-only answers, inject some explanation too.